# Explanation for derivative of $x*e^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hello could someone explain me why exactly is the derivative of $f(x)$ is the following:

$ f(x) = x * e^x \rightarrow 
      f'(x)   = e^x + x e^x
         = e^x ( 1 + x)$

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just apply the product rule

Comment: @sanjab could you please elaborate? I would be realy greateful

Comment: @BogdanM: Do you know the product rule? Do you know that $e^x$ is its own derivative? If so, I don't really see anything to explain. (Can you be more specific?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the product rule stating that for a function consisting of a product, the following applies;

$$f(x) = u(x) \cdot v(x)$$

$$f'(x) = u'(x)\cdot v(x) + u(x) \cdot v'(x)$$

For your function, we can set $$u = x$$ $$v = e^x$$

Giving us $$u' = 1$$ $$v' = e^x$$

Note: I'm using shorthand, meaning $u = u(x)$ and $v = v(x)$. Just for simplicity.

Anyway, plugging this into the formula;

$$f'(x) = u'v + uv' = 1e^x + xe^x = e^x(1+x)$$

Extra notes: During this, we're using a few rules of differentiation that I assume you're familiar with, namely that the derivative of $x$ with respect to $x$ is 1. Also, that $e^x$ is its own derivative. If you are unfamiliar with this, my advice is to jump back a few steps, because you've missed out, or forgotten a few things along the way.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now  :)